# When android system will append raw://<file_path> to the any file user choose from android device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, filepath

I am trying to choose an image from the gallery app but it is observed that path for that particular file contains appended `raw://` path Like : `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/Test1.jpeg.`

Answer (score 0):

That is not a path.

That is a `Uri` with a `content` scheme, from a `ContentProvider`. Everything after `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents` (the scheme and authority) is up to the `ContentProvider`, and it does not have to have any meaning to you or anyone else.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but when actually the content provider gives you that path which contains "raw://"? In my observation when I rename the file name and if I choose that renamed file then it will give path including "raw://". I don't know why it happens?

Comment: @sspider: "when actually the content provider gives you that path which contains "raw://"?" -- as I wrote, that is not a path.

Comment: Sorry for calling it a "path". but as per the your comment it is Uri with content sceme and everything after content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents (the scheme and authority) is up to the ContentProvider but I want to know why content provider add "raw://" at the end after renaming any file and if I choose that file.

Comment: @sspider: "I want to know why content provider add "raw://" at the end" -- that was up to the developers of that `ContentProvider`. We cannot tell you why they made the decisions that they made.